# Need case-sensitive formatting (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub test(sToken As String)
    Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=sToken
    Cells.FormatConditions(Cells.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Cells.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternLightVertical
        .PatternColorIndex = 4
        .ColorIndex = 10
    End With
    Cells.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

The problem with the code above is, when I use **Call test("a")** (for example) I get formatted cells with
"a" and "A", but I want just an "a".
Any suggestions?

PS: not skilled in VBA and English, please don't kill =)

---

Ok, here the full macro for better understanding problem (with my crappy coding skills =P )

```
Sub FormatTokens()
    Call FormatReset   'Clear formatting
    Call SetFormatting("d", xlPatternNone, 1, 44)
    Call SetFormatting("h", xlPatternCrissCross, 46, 44)
    Call SetFormatting("t", xlPatternLightVertical, 4, 10) ' Here the 1st conflict token 
    Call SetFormatting("p", xlPatternNone, 1, 10)
    Call SetFormatting("T", xlPatternNone, 4, 10) ' And here another
    Call SetFormatting("v", xlPatternGray16, 49, 24)
' Blah, blah, blah in the same style...
End Sub
Private Sub SetFormatting(sToken As String, oPat As XlPattern, iPatCol As Integer, iCol As Integer)
    Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=sToken
    Cells.FormatConditions(Cells.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Cells.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .Pattern = oPat
        .PatternColorIndex = iPatCol
        .ColorIndex = iCol
    End With
    Cells.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Macro do the job, but not with "t" and "T" tokens

Comment: Is it correct to say you want to format all cells where the data case matches the `sToken` case as well as the value?

Comment: Right. Moreover, the final routine takes some additional parameters (different formatting) and goes several times for auto highlighting cells by content.

Comment: Your new code is too static... see my comments and udpate.

Comment: Just for test purposes, refactor in future...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some deep readings of couple forums I found what I needed.
Here the solution, suitable in many different situations: set custom event handlers =)
Steps for set `Worksheet` events from VBA:
1. Create class module, which will be Your event handler (named `clsWorksheetEventHandler` in my case)
2. Code him:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents WorksheetEvents As Worksheet 'As an object whose events should be handled

Private Sub WorksheetEvents_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 'Event to handle
    'Some code You need to handle this event
End Sub
```

3. In Your working module add subroutines to initialize and terminate handling:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oWorksheetEventHandler As clsWorksheetEventHandler 'Ref for Your class
Dim colWorksheetEventHandlers As Collection 'For all referrals

Sub WorksheetEventHandlers_initialize()
    'Create new Collection to store ours handlers
    Set colWorksheetEventHandlers = New Collection 
    'Loop through worksheets
    For Each Worksheet In Worksheets
        'Create new instance of the event handler class
        Set WorksheetEventHandler = New clsWorksheetEventHandler 
        'Set it to handle events in worksheet
        Set WorksheetEventHandler.WorksheetEvents = Worksheet
        'And add it to our collection
        colWorksheetEventHandlers.Add WorksheetEventHandler
    Next Worksheet
End Sub

Sub WorksheetEwentHandlers_terminate()
    'Loop through our collection
    For Each WorksheetEventHandler In colWorksheetEventHandlers
    'Clear event handler
    Set WorksheetEventHandler = Nothing
Next WorksheetEventHandler
'And finally clear memory
Set colWorksheetEventHandlers = Nothing
End Sub
```

4. ?????????????????????
5. PROFIT!!!!!!

I hope You enjoy =)

---

PS: Here are some links that have helped me greatly
[How to create application-level event handlers in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213566/en-us)
[Controlling multiple textboxes on a userform](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=80631)

Comment: That isn't exact what I asked, but is real solution in my situation. Think about this like some crutches ;)

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly specify `Upper Case`, `Lower Case` formatting.

Add the condition to check,

```
if UCase(range.value) = UCase(sToken) then 
// do formatting
end if
```

**EDIT**

This works:

```
Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:="=EXACT($B1,""a"")"
```

But this doesn't:

```
sToken = "=EXACT($A1, """"" & sToken & """"")"
Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:=sToken
```

Comment: can help, but it will be wild crutches (google translate =)). Because I need format cells with "a" and "A" (but different). It better seen in added code.

Comment: Your first code is formatting both "a" and "A". `Code(A1) = 97` and `Exact(A1,"a")` working. However it doesn't work when passed by a string to the Formula...

Comment: First and second codes formatting both "t" and "T" by _one type of formatting_ (2nd code just override "t" format by `Call SetFormatting("T", xlPatternNone, 4, 10)` ), but I need _different formatting_ for "t" and "T" values. Problem in `Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:=sToken`, because it is case-insensitive in both codes. Sorry for unclear explanation of the problem.

Comment: Hmm, is `Cells.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
Formula1:="=EXACT($B1,""a"")"` need a constant in B1 for matching? If so, it unacceptable, I can't modify user sheets...

Comment: @user1927236 in that case, it's best you check your `sToken` case using `code()`, then run two different conditions 1. for lowercase, 2. ther for uppercase. This way it keeps your code clean :)

Comment: Yes, it helps in "t" and "T" situation. But, let say, we have tokens like "foo", "Foo", "fOO" ets and all of them need _different_ format? As I understand each cell have stack with conditions and each condition have params like "with which to interact" (Type), "how to interact" (Operator) and "with what to interact" (Formula1/2). If "Operator" gets _true_, then formatting is applied, am I right? Or `Formula1:=true` enough?

Comment: Also, we can `Operator:=xlExpression` and do all job in `Formula1`... Any _case-sensitive_ string comparison func? But we need to get value of abstract cell (we interact with all cells, not a range) into that func...  My brain just leaked :|

Comment: Maybe we can get variable from `Type` somehow and use it in `Formula1`?

Comment: Ok, founded something: `CBool(InStrB(sToken, sCellValue))` - here we search `sCellValue` _in_ `sToken` what emulate EXACT func =) Only problem: set value of cell as `sCellValue` in it's personal FormatConditions stack (maybe some special variable/constant, representing value of cell like `xlCellValue` in Type).

Answer (score 0):

Use:
`Formula1:= "=EXACT(A1;""" & sToken & """)"`

Or:

`Formula1:="=EXACT(" & Cells(1, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1) & ";""" & sToken & """)"`

If you want to apply to a subrange you can simply change that part.